# Cron job to Mount AWS EFS on Startup - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a Ubuntu 18 Version and AWS EFS storage which i am mounting as NFS. I created a script called mount.sh and gave exe permission. I am able to run the script and the EFS is getting mounted.
I wanted this to be auto executed during the system start up.

I created a sudo crontab - e with below command

```
@reboot sleep 120 /script/mount.sh
```

Mount.sh has the below command

```
   sudo mount -t nfs4 -o  
   nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport  
   fs-xxxxxx.efs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:/ /efs
```

Can you help me with mounting this EFS on system startup. Very new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of your requirement what I get is you want to mount AWS EFS with EC2 on reboot or startup. For those who still looking for a solution to mount EFS with EC2 on startup/reboot, My Answer to this Question might help them.

Instead of creating a cronjob, you can use the `fstab`

Steps to mount EFS on startup:

1. sudo nano /etc/fstab
2. Add below line at the bottom of the file: `fs-xxxxxx.efs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:/ /efs nfs4 _netdev 0 0`
3. Then press `Ctrl + x` to save the file.

This way your EFS will automatically mount on reboot
For more information, you can watch [this video](https://www.google.com/search?q=mount%20efs%20tutorial&oq=mount%20efs%20tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57.8192j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_Ph_EXorIO9iS9QPXi6N445)

I hope this will help you! Good Luck.